# Show multiple locations on google map

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to access google maps in iphone to show the multiple locations of the Branch-centers in 1 city/area,
any help?
Please have look at the following image.

[image: look like this image]

thanks,

Comment: Ask Google..i mean google around...

Comment: I'm not quite sure how google maps can help you fetching the current location of your buddies. I mean, its not a livestream but static photos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this blog will help, specially for maps,
see the following link-

[click here](http://mayurbirari.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/how-to-access-mkmapkit-in-iphone/)